# How to draw a Cartesian plane via OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, math, geometry, cartesian-coordinates

I need to draw a Cartesian plane (standard OXYZ), where i would construct planes from equations ax+by+cz+d=0 and some objects.

How can i do that via OpenGL? Anybody?

Comment: Do you really just want to draw planes? If you want to draw arbitrary 3d-surfaces, take a look at the marching cubes algorithm. It is used to transfer the implicit surface definition to actual geometry. Another algorithm to do this is dual contouring.

Comment: In reality, i want to draw a Cartesian plane and then some various geometric 3D-objects on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create triangle or quad. Calculate points in plane using your equation and from those points construct geometry.

For rendering geometry, look for some tutorials. There are plenty of them around.

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you just want to draw the axes of the Cartesian planes xy, xz, yz.

You can achieve this very easily by drawing a non-solid cube (*glutWireCube* should do the job), such that its bottom-front-left corner is at (0,0,0) (or bottom-back-left corner, based on the direction of positive depth).